# Router.beforeEach jumps back to login page and resets vuex state value after login

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vue-router, quasar-framework

So i am trying to change `isSignedIn` in vuex state by clicking the sign-in button, current behaviour is, after pressing the signin button, `isSignedIn` change from false to true for a second, during this time url jumps from `http://localhost:8080/Login` to `http://localhost:8080/?#` then `http://localhost:8080/Login` with the `isSignedIn` as false.

Below is my code, what did i do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

components/Login.vue methods:

```
    async signIn() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('storage/actionSignIn')
      await this.$router.push({path: '/'})
    }
  }
```

action.js

```
export async function actionSignIn ({ commit }, payload) {
  commit('mutationIsSignIn')
}
```

mutation.js

```
export const mutationIsSignIn = (state, payload) => {
  state.isSignedIn = true
}
```

state.js

```
isSignedIn: false,
```

getter.js

```
export function getterIsSignedIn (state) {
  return state.isSignedIn
}
```

router/index.js

```
export default function ({store /*, ssrContext */}) {
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  })
  Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let isSignIn = store.getters["storage/getterIsSignedIn"]
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      if (!isSignIn) {
        next('/Login')
      }
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
  return Router
```

router/routes.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/Login',
    component: () => import('pages/Login.vue'),
    meta: { guest: true },
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/Home',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {path: '/', component: () => import('pages/Dashboard2.vue')},
      {path: '/Profile', component: () => import('pages/UserProfile.vue')},
      {path: '/ProjectList', component: () => import('pages/ProjectList.vue')},
      {path: '/CrmUserList', component: () => import('pages/CrmUserList.vue')},
      {path: '/ClientList', component: () => import('pages/ClientList')},
      {path: '/SalesDataList', component: () => import('pages/SalesDataList')},
      {path: '/CategoryList', component: () => import('pages/CategoryList')},
      {path: '/DailyReportList', component: () => import('pages/DailyReportList')},
      {path: '/Upload', component: () => import('pages/Upload.vue')}
    ],
    meta: { requiresAuth: true }
  },
  {
    path: '/Lock',
    component: () => import('pages/LockScreen.vue'),
    meta: { guest: true },
  },
  {
    path: '/Maintenance',
    component: () => import('pages/Maintenance.vue'),
    meta: { guest: true },
  },
  {
    path: '/Lock-2',
    component: () => import('pages/LockScreen-2.vue'),
    meta: { guest: true },
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, How have you defined your getter?

Comment: I have updated the getter method, would you mind take a llok again?